# Inline table-valued function without a parameter

Tags: sql, azure, datetime, azure-sql-database, ssms

I am still pretty new to Azure platform, and learning SQL language.  I have a question about creating a user-defined inline Table-valued function (without need a parameter) on Azure platform.  Since accessing to Azure platform on my SQL Server Management Studio, whenever I create a log file by using the system built-in function **GetDate()**, it shows the date and time in UTC time zone, but I want my current time zone (Easter Time Zone) which is 4 hours behind of UTC.  So, I am wondering if anyone can please guide me how I can create a inline-table-valued function that does not need any parameter, and able to use it as **GetDate()** function by simply running as below:

```
            SELECT GetDate()
```

This is my attempt and I know this is not correct, but at least I tried.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Azure_EST_GetDate()] (
)

RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

    SELECT DATEADD(hh,-4,GETDATE()) AS 'handate'
)
GO
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: FYI an in-line table-valued function without parameters is the same as a view! Rather create a view instead. It's simpler and you'll have a better change the SQL query optimiser will make a faster as well. However, in this case, a scalar UDF is better though, as @DanGuzman well describes below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `DATETIMEOFFSET` and `AT TIMEZONE` instead of `DATEADD`. This will properly convert times across time zones and apply the appropriate time change rules. You can convert the `DATETIMEOFFSET` result to another type (`datetime2` in this example) if needed.

I don't think your intent is to include the parenthesis in the function name so I removed it in this example.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Azure_EST_GetDate] (
)

RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AS datetime2(3)) AS handate
);
GO
```

**EDIT**

A table-valued function can generally be used in queries wherever a table may be specified. For example:

```
SELECT handate FROM dbo.Azure_EST_GetDate();
```

Table-valued functions are appropriate when more than one column or row is returned. You could alternatively use a scalar function for your need since a scalar (single) value is returned. Below is the equivalent scalar function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Azure_EST_GetDate_Scalar] ()
RETURNS datetime2(3)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' AS datetime2(3));
END;
GO
```

This scalar function can be used instead of `GETDATE()` in Azure SQL Database to return a local time:

```
SELECT dbo.Azure_EST_GetDate_Scalar() AS handate;
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, and it works as I expected. I appreciated it.

Comment: since this newly created (table-valued function) will replace GetDate() function, so I am just curious if I want to use it in my stored procedure, like returning the result as a scalar function, so can you guide me how I can change it/use it? Thanks !

Comment: @harrisonthu, I added usage examples to my answer along with a scalar function example.